# How to move from one Form to another using Yii framework

Tags: yii

I want to collect input in a form using yii framework. When I validate this input and it is correct, I redirect the user to another Form in the same application.
I have validated the input and move to another page but unable to move to another input form.
Please Can Somebody help Me with this?

Comment: Can you please add some code - what do you mean you can not move to another input form?

Comment: If you are using tabular forms then you can manage it using javascript, but if you are redirecting it to new form then you have to manage it through session.

Comment: Thank you very much after a serious reflection I finally succeeded Yesterday.

Comment: $this->redirect('/third/index.php?r=site/Information');